# Unable To Pass Image Data Back To Android Application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera-intent

I have been trying to pass the image data back to the app after capturing it. However, it always crash while trying to return to the my app.

The Code for starting the intent is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Upload);
    snap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Snap);
    select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Select);
    subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Subject);
    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Message);snap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
             getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.jpg";  
             File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath); 
             Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri

             Intent it = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
             it.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri); 
             startActivityForResult(it, CAMERA_RESULT);
            }
        });
}
```

The code to receive the intent is:

```
 case CAMERA_RESULT:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    // Get Extra from the intent 
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); 
                    // Get the returned image from extra 
                    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); 

                    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView); 
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
              }
        break;
```

I also receive the following exceptions when the app crash occurred:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.NYP.estatemanagement/com.NYP.estatemanagement.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.NYP.estatemanagement/com.NYP.estatemanagement.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this is working like charm with me**

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It manages to sent the image data back to the app without crashing. Can I ask another two question? Is there a way to have a bigger image size? second question: Is there a way to persistently store have the image appearing when orientation is change or when the app is return from pause? Once again, thanks for the help =D

Answer (score 0):

this (below) from @Biraj Zalavadia (answer) :

```
public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

and

```
String selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
```

is all I needed